# $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ is generated by two elements as a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

Consider continuous complex-valued functions on real line which vanish at infinity
$$
C_0 (\mathbb{R}) := \{f\in C(\mathbb{R}):\lim_{|t|\to+\infty}f(t) = 0,f(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{C}\}
$$
as a $C^*$-algebra under the pointwise conjugation. In [HG04](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-39702-1_3) one talks about suspension algebra and KK-theory/E-theory and the author states that
$$
C_0 (\mathbb{R}) := \overline{C^* [u,v]},\quad\quad u(x) = e^{-x^2},\,v(x)= xe^{-x^2} \in C_0(\mathbb{R}) 
$$
as $C^*$-algebra.($\overline{(..)}$ is taking closure under the $C^*$-norm on $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ which is pointwise maximal norms)

I do not know how to derive this results. This maybe relates to some approxiamation theorems by Hermite polynomials(What I Guess)? If somebody could figure it out I'll be much grateful.

The ultimate aim of this question is a starting point of $KK$-theory, where $C^*$-algebra $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ stands in a crucial stage in amplification of $C^*$-algebra. In [HG04](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-39702-1_3) one define a coalgebra structure:
$$
\Delta: C_0(\mathbb{R}) \to C_0(\mathbb{R})\widehat{\otimes}C_0(\mathbb{R})
$$
And I do not know how to computer the relations below:
$$
\qquad \Delta(u) = u\widehat{\otimes} u, \Delta(v) = u\widehat{\otimes} v + v \widehat{\otimes} u
$$
where $\widehat{\otimes}$ is the minimal tensor product of $C^*$-algebra.

And $\Delta(f)$ is defined as the limit of functional calculation of $f(\mathrm{Id}_{[-R,R]}\widehat{\otimes} 1 + 1\widehat{\otimes} \mathrm{Id}_{[-R,R]})$, where $1,\mathrm{Id}_{[-R,R]} \in \mathcal{S}_R =
C_0 (\mathbb{R})/ \mathrm{ker}\mathrm{(-)|}_{[-R,R]}$.

This issue is about suspension algebra $S(A):= C_0 (\mathbb{R})\otimes A$.
But I do not know how to compute the $\Delta$ map. Can some experts on KK-theory and analytic index theory give some explanations?

Appreciating any useful comments.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone-Weierstrass_theorem#Stone–Weierstrass_theorem,_C*-algebra_version

Comment: There is a more challenging problem: show that the functions of the form $p(x)e^{-x^2},$ where $p$ is a polynomial, are dense in $C_0(\mathbb{R}).$ Your problem follows directly from the Stone-Weierstrass theorem applied to the continuous function space  on the one point compactification of the real line.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks for comment. I think there is a little difference. In $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ there is no nonzero constant functions and every element is not invertible. It can be viewed as a $C^*$ ideal of $C(\mathbb{S}^{1})$. And maybe Anne Bauval's link is more worth to ponder?(Stone-Weierstrass in C*-algebra verison)

Comment: I referred to the locally compact version of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, which is an easy consequence of that theorem for compact space, through one point compactification of the underlying locally compact space. For a compact space $X$  if the algebra separates point then its closure is equal to $C(X)$ or to the subspace of $C(X)$ consisting of all continuous functions vanishing at a point $x_0\in X.$ You can find the locally compact version at the link provided by Anne Bauval.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks a lot. I'll go to check it.